# Wifi Chat between android and PC

Tags: android, wifi

I was working on a application where i needed to establish a communication between android and PC to transfer some data over wi-fi. I am able to communicate between two PC's over wifi. So code from PC side is ready. I needed a reference to use Wifi from android side. Something similar to bluetooth chat is helpful. I am able to scan Wifi networks present in android but not able to proceed further. 
Cheers

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you want transferred between android and PC? What OS is the PC running? Do you need a reliable (TCP) connection or an unreliable but fast (UDP) connection? It's highly unlikely you'll be able to take the code from the 'PC side' and use it immediately for Android, some changes will need to be made, even if its to recognise "okay, this connection is from a phone".

Comment: Ya i need a TCP connection. I have  already established a connection between PC and Bluetooth using TCP. And code from PC side is a server code waiting for a connection from client. I want to work my android as a client. I am transferring data like simple protocols and images. OS in the PC is windows.

Answer (score 1):

This one receives a file

```
private String ReceiveFile() {

    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        Socket os = null;

        try {
            os = socket.accept();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            if (!socket.isClosed()) socket.close();
            return "TIMEOUT";
        }

        InputStream bos = os.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);
        DataOutputStream bw = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        int Total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while (true) {
            read = bos.read(buffer);
            if (read <= 0) break;
            bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
            Total = Total + read;
        }

        if (!socket.isClosed()) socket.close();
        return "SUCCESS";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "FAILURE";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you trying to achieve it is difficult to be more specific but this snippet receives a short data burst.

```
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORTNUMBER);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[50];

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    serverSocket.close();
```